# Purchase of this item is not currently available

Tags: ios, itunes, in-app-purchase

I have tried to purchase something in the ios game of sandbox environment,use Test User,after i entered the appid and passward,i got the message:

"
Purchase of this item is not currently available.
This item is being modified.  Please try again later
"

it works fine yesterday,i change nothing,but it can't work today. I'm unsure what the cause is.

many thanks.

Comment: Don't worry I think it's just apple server problem. I just created the in app purchase item several hours ago and doing testing on it. And I got the same error message.

Comment: Same here.... poo... good thing I am not under a deadline. NOT

Comment: happend to me too, i think it resolved itself, now i have some othe itunes issues

Comment: Happening to me today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two possible ways this error to be happened.

1. If you changed the details of the product ID on the IAP, It may take 
   some more time to process
2. Coding and user control is up to you click buy on the alert after clicking "Buy"
   asking apple ID, password and further are in the control of StoreKit framework
   that is It may be a server problem while processing on the App Store.